# linq query where column contains null values

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have the following query

```
Dim get_rmf_2 = From rmf In t_rmf _
      Where rmf!NIVP = nivp_rap
```

When i run it i get an error :

```
Operator '=' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and string "test".
```

I suspect this is because the column "NIVP" in the datatable contains null values, I've tried yhe same thing without null values and it works.

So how can i make this work ? ; the column "NIVP" really has a row "test" , and a normal SQL query works fine.

Comment: What does the rmf!NIVP do? It looks like you might have processed the query into memory and are then evaluating it. Normally LINQ would perform the query in the database and handle this case for you.

Comment: well it's querying a datatable (t_rmf) rmf!NIVP referes to a column of that datatable.
I will change this in the question also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with VB syntax for LINQ but you could try something like this:

```
Dim get_rmf_2 = From rmf In t_rmf _
      Where Not IsDBNull(rmf!NIVP) AndAlso rmf!NIVP = nivp_rap
```